# Find the reduction formula for the following integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

$$
    \mathrm{(b)} \quad\quad J_n = \int \tan^{2n}(x) \sec^3(x) \;\mathrm{d}x
$$
I have no idea how to start this question when it comes to the reduction formula. I know there are some cases for when the power of tan is odd or the power of sec is even, but not sure how to substitute for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint
\begin{align*}
J_{n}&=\int\tan^{2n}{x}(\sec{x})d\tan{x}\\
&=\tan^{2n+1}{x}\sec{x}-\int\tan{x}[2n\tan^{2n-1}{x}\sec^3{x}+\tan^{2n+1}\sec{x}]dx\\
&=\tan^{2n+1}{x}\sec{x}-2nJ_{n}-\int\tan^{2n+2}{x}\sec{x}dx\\
&=\tan^{2n+1}{x}\sec{x}-2nJ_{n}-\int \tan^{2n}{x}(\sec^2{x}-1)\sec{x}dx\\
&=\tan^{2n+1}{x}\sec{x}-2nJ_{n}-J_{n}+\int\tan^{2n}{x}\sec{x}dx
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
H_{n}&=\int\tan^{2n}{x}\sec{x}dx=\int\tan^{2n-1}{x}d\sec{x}\\
&=\tan^{2n-1}{x}\sec{x}-(2n-1)\int\tan^{2n-2}{x}\sec^3{x}dx\\
&=\tan^{2n-1}{x}\sec{x}-(2n-1)J_{n-1}
\end{align*}
so
$$J_{n}=\tan^{2n+1}{x}\sec{x}-(2n+1)J_{n}+\tan^{2n-1}{x}\sec{x}-(2n-1)J_{n-1}$$
$$\Longrightarrow (2n+2)J_{n}+(2n-1)J_{n-1}=\tan^{2n-1}{x}\sec^3{x}$$